# AWS CDK retrieving resources ID [Python]

Tags: aws-cdk

Newbie question but I am trying to get the Id for my VPC or/and the subnetsID that were created using CDK Python.

For more details , I am trying to create a vpc and then using RAM share private subnets to my org.

I have tried vpcName.vpc_id and I get back a {$Token} and I have tried many other things with no luck.

Please note that by using boto3 and hardcoding the vpc-id I was able to complete the above but it is not really portable!

Thanks all,

Mazza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can help you. But it will only work while deployment using "cdk deploy".

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "TheVPC",
    cidr="10.0.0.0/16"
)

# Iterate the private subnets
selection = vpc.select_subnets(
    subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE # Can change to PUBLIC or ISOLATED
)

# Read the Subnet
for subnet in selection.subnets:
    pass
```

Comment: Must be doing something wrong as I am only getting back this list (Class Objects)

[<aws_cdk.aws_ec2.PrivateSubnet object at 0x1059d9350>, <aws_cdk.aws_ec2.PrivateSubnet object at 0x1059d9b10>]

Comment: Yes, But we can't see output like this. To see output we use CFnOutput. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/CfnOutput.html)